# Jmeter 5.5 error with assertion value type, string not equal to int

Tags: java, json, jmeter, assertion

I have a test that used to work perfect in jmeter 5.4.1. Then I upgraded to jmeter 5.5 recently and all JSON assertions stopped working.

this is the message I get from all JSON assertions :

Assertion failure message:Value expected to be '8', but found '8'

the value is the same, but I realized that now it checks the type (string != number), but in previous versions, it used to work.

this is my Json assert :
[image]

And this is an example of the JSON response :

```
{
  "person": {
    "age": "8"
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to disable the type check or how to make it works like previous versions?

If I change the JSON assertion value like this, it works :

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98GKg.png)]

The problem is that I have a lot of tests, and it's better for me to find a different solution, like enable/disable a parameter, or something like that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a side-effect of the bug fix for the JMeter Issue [5543](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/5534), you might want to [report it](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Looking into [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/JSONPathAssertion.java#L177):

```
Object expected = JSONValue.parse(getExpectedValue());
```

there is no possibility to revert to the previous behaviour via property. You might want to tick "Match as regular expression" box:

[image]

however it might break more complex assertions especially if they contain [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)

So you either need to downgrade and wait for the decision or scan assertion failure messages using [JSR223 Assertion and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and set the assertion result as passed if "expected" and "found" values are equal

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with jmeter version > 5.5. Setting the expected value as "8" fixed it.
Basically, if expected value is of type string, it must be enclosed in double-quotes, specially numeric values.